# How to fetch the Not Found Exception in cakePHP 2 Paginator Component

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

I use the Paginator Component and whenever a user/bot goes to a page number that is to high, he will get a Not Found Exception.
This could be fine, but I would like to redirect the user with 301 back to the first page.

Now I know that the [cakePHP 2 documentation][1] tells me how to do it for individual cases but I want to do it for all pagination without adding the code bit every time.

I tried to build my own Paginator Component in my App, with the Core Component as Parent but since I don't have name spaces, I simply call my own Component and end in a loop

```
    <?php

    App::uses('PaginatorComponent', 'Vendor/Controller/Component');

    class PaginatorComponent extends PaginatorComponent {

        public function paginate($object = null, $scope = array(), $whitelist = array()) {
            try {
                PaginatorComponent::paginate($object, $scope, $whitelist);
            } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
                if ($this->request->query('page') <= 1) {
                    throw new NotFoundException();
                }
                $this->redirect($this->here);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call your component `PaginatorComponent` as this already exists! This line should ring alarm bells straight away:-

```
class PaginatorComponent extends PaginatorComponent {
```

Instead name your component something different like `CustomPaginatorComponent`:-

```
class CustomPaginatorComponent extends PaginatorComponent {
```

You will also want to call `parent::paginate()` in your custom `paginate()` method rather than `PaginatorComponent::paginate()`.